# How to add prompt code into othere code in sas?

Tags: sas

I have created Date prompt in SAS EG "Start_DT" & "END_DT" now I want to pass this user defined values from other programe?
I have link this two program (Prompt + Program) but not able get pass the values of Prompt..
Thanks in Advance..!

Answer (score 2):

Edit your prompts and tick the box "Use prompt value throughout project" - that will make your macro variables global.